# Telerik MVC Grid ClientEvents are never fired

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using the following code to fire the client events and the events are not being fired:

**Telerik MVC Grid**

```
@Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Customers)
               .ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowDataBound("onDataBound"))
               .... further code
```

**Event**

```
 function onDataBound(sender,eventArgs) { alert(eventArgs);}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are using server binding, client events are fired with ajax binding only. You may refer to the grid's documentation [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#OnDataBound).

Answer (score 1):

the script should look like below:

```
function onDataBound(e) {
    alert(e)
}
```

That should fix the problem.